# Do all connections on a server need to be SSL?

Tags: express, ssl, socket.io, peerjs

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm completely stumped. My task is to enhance an application that I didn't write myself. It's based on Express, Socket.io and peerjs for video chat. In order to test the application on several devices I need to access it over network. However, this doesn't work because getUserMedia() - which I need for peerjs - only works over SSL.

I've never worked with SSL before and I constantly get "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" or "ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH" errors. The problem is that right now I'm not sure what I actually have to do. Is it enough to config peerjs for SSL? Or do I have to config Socket.io as well? The application consists of a server and a client application. Do I have to configurate the client as well?

Answer (score 0):

To answer only and purely your headline question

- it's totally 100% OK for a Node/express/sockets type of server, to run, with no SSL

For example, I'm just now looking at a client which connects to `ws://blah.blah.io:80` which is an aws server - node/express/sockets.

On the server we use the amazing /ws library https://github.com/websockets/ws

and the code to allow connections in to the server

```
 const WebSocket = require('ws');
 ...
 wss.on('connection', function connection(u) { ...
```

is all fine and it's used by zillions of clients. No https.  Of course on AWS you have to open the port etc.

Hope this answers one part of your question.